# How to handle missing tag when parsing xml using DOM?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I'm trying to do XML parsing using DOM, but the problem is that the  tag is missing in some places. Tell me how to handle this case so that in its absence, some other string is written to the ArrayList (for example, "No data")? I'm new to Java. I did it according to the tutorial

XML of similar content:

```
<item>
<title>number 1</title>
</item>

<item>
<title>number 2</title>
<enclosure url="https://www.google.com/"/>
</item>
```

Part of the Java Code:

```
List<String> title = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<String> enclosure = new ArrayList<>();

NodeList itemNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (int i = 0; i < itemNodeList.getLength(); i++){
    if (itemNodeList.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
        Element itemElement = (Element) itemNodeList.item(i);

        NodeList childNodes = itemElement.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++){
            if (childNodes.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element childElement = (Element) childNodes.item(j);
                
                switch (childElement.getNodeName()){
                    case "title":{
                        title.add(childElement.getTextContent());  
                        break;
                    }
                    case "enclosure":{
                        String info = childElement.getAttribute("url");
                        enclosure.add(info); 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to parse invalid XML? The expected result is an error.

Comment: your question isn't really about xml parsing.  you are really asking how to handle data which you expect to be there, which is not (the xml itself is valid).  this is entirely up to you as the developer.  if the data is allowed to be missing, then you should just keep going.  if the data is required, then you should throw an exception or return some other appropriate error to the user.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: @jtahlborn Please distinguish between well-formed and valid. A document is valid when it passed the grammar (=schema) test.

Comment: @aled Valid/invalid XML requires a schema check. As long as that is not happening, all he is trying to parse is wellformed XML, or he gets some syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tell me how to handle this case so that in its absence, some other string is written to the ArrayList (for example, "No data")?

If you want defaults for the "title" and "enclosure" values, then set them, on a per-item basis.  For example,

```
        // ...
        Element itemElement = (Element) itemNodeList.item(i);
        String itemTitle = "No title";
        String itemEnclosure = "no data";
        // ...
```

Then replace those appropriately as you parse the child nodes, instead of immediately updating your lists.  For example,

```
                    // ...
                    case "enclosure":{
                        itemEnclosure = childElement.getAttribute("url");
                        break;
                    }
                    // ...
```

After you have processed all the children of each item node, you have the appropriate information to add to your lists, whether it was read from child nodes or remains the default:

```
        // ...
        for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++){
            // ...
        }
        title.add(itemTitle);
        enclosure.add(itemEnclosure);
        // ...
```

---

Be aware, however, that if any of your items contain more than one title or more than one enclosure, then some of those will not be captured.  If you want to be able to support multiples like that then you need a different internal representation for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing XML into a DOM structure, for that all you need is a syntactically correct XML document. Insiders will talk about a 'well formed' document.

Now you want to enforce that only specific tags are being used, and maybe you want to enforce they occur in the right amount or sequence. This is where you need to define which tags, how often and in what order they should appear.
Such information goes into a grammar, which would be defined in an [XML Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)). A document that passed a grammar check is called valid.

The W3C has a very nice introduction into the topic called [XML Schema Part0: Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/).

If you believe that is too much to deal with for your small example, you can put the validation into your application. On the DOM tree check whether an element has the expected child node. Or check if it has the expected attribute. If it is missing, your code may make use of a default value.
But if your document is getting complex, the schema based approach will all of a sudden look simpler and easier to maintain.